# Call custom MembershipProvider without casting Membership.Provider

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-membership, membership-provider, sqlmembershipprovider, custom-membershipprovider

Is there a way to call the custom MembershipProvider I have implemented in code without having to cast the Membership class to my custom provider every time?  For example, I setup my web.config like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="TestDB"
         connectionString="conn_str_here"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<membership defaultProvider="CustomSqlMembershipProvider">
    <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="CustomSqlMembershipProvider" type="Common.CustomSqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="TestDB"
         enablePasswordRetrieval="false" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="false"
         maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5" minRequiredPasswordLength="6" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" passwordAttemptWindow="10"
         applicationName="/" />
    </providers>
</membership>
```

And my custom provider class:

```
namespace Common 
{
    public class CustomSqlMembershipProvider : SqlMembershipProvider
    {
        public void ChangeUsername()
        {
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Now to call my new custom function, is there some way to allow `Membership.ChangeUsername()` versus having to do this:

```
CustomSqlMembershipProvider customMembership = Membership.Provider as CustomSqlMembershipProvider;
customMembership.ChangeUsername();
```

Doing the cast everywhere you want to use it starts to get annoying after a while. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You could add an extension method:

```
namespace System.Web.Membership
{
    public static class MembershipProviderExtensions
    {
        public static void ChangeUsername(this MembershipProvider provider, string oldUsername, string newUsername)
        {
            var customProvider = provider as CustomSqlMembershipProvider;
            if (customProvider == null) throw new Exception("Invalid provider type.");

            customProvider.ChangeUsername(oldUsername, newUsername);
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Membership.Provider.ChangeUsername("bob", "jane");
```